# Цикл не выводит значения в нужном количестве

Tags: python, matplotlib, визуализация

Застрял с небольшим циклом:
Питон ругается что длины списков x и y разной длины, и поэтому не строит график:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes
> (69,) and (1,)

Очевидно проблема в цикле, только вот не пойму никак что не так...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
Lmax = 34.367
d_2 = 80
d_1 = 44
d_0 = 20
b_2 = d_2 / 12
fi_0 = 5
F_0 = np.pi * (d_1 ** 2 - d_0 ** 2) * np.cos(np.deg2rad(fi_0)) / 4
F_2 = np.pi * d_2 * b_2
 
 
s = np.arange(0, Lmax, 0.5)
 
def F(s):
    for j in s:
        if j < 10:
            return F_0
        else:
            return (F_2 - F_0) * (j - 10) / (Lmax - 10) + F_0
 
 
fig4 = plt.figure("Изменение площади проходного сечения колеса по длине центроиды")
graph4 = plt.plot(s, F(s))
print('Plot: ', len(graph4), graph4)
grid4 = plt.grid(True)  # линии вспомогательной сетки
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема вашего кода в том, что первый же `return` возвращает одно значение из функции, цикл прерывается и дальше функция не выполняется. По-хорошему получающиеся значения нужно накапливать в массиве и возвращать из функции весь этот массив целиком, а это требует некоторой переделки кода (см. ответ S.Nick).

Но есть и простой способ исправить ваш код - поменять в вашей функции оба `return` на `yield` и потом ещё превратить результат вызова функции в список (иначе `matplotlib` ругается, что не умеет в генераторы), и всё заработает, потому что функция вернёт значение не один раз, а сделает это на каждой итерации цикла, как и было, видимо, задумано, только вы не знали, как это можно сделать в питоне:

```
def F(s):
    for j in s:
        if j < 10:
            yield F_0
        else:
            yield (F_2 - F_0) * (j - 10) / (Lmax - 10) + F_0
...
graph4 = plt.plot(s, list(F(s)))
```

[image: plot-yield]

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю свои пять копеек: **Очень плохая идея использовать циклы с `numpy` данными (с циклами катастрофично падает скорость выполнения).** `numpy` предполагает "думать векторно", поэтому ваша функция `F(s)` должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
def F(s):
    out = (F_2 - F_0) * (s - 10) / (Lmax - 10) + F_0
    out[s < 10] =  F_0
    return out
```

или так:

```
def F(s):
    out = F_0 * np.ones(s.shape)
    out[s >= 10] += (F_2 - F_0) * (s[s >= 10] - 10) / (Lmax - 10)
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно неверно написана функция F(s). Она всегда возвращает единичное значение, при s=0,  а не массив, как вы наверное ожидаете. Соответственно -  и нарисовать график невозможно -  по одной оси 69 значений, по другой  - 1. Не знаю, что вы хотели в этой функции сделать -  не ее надо категорически исправить.